# How to access servlet-context in jsp/struts2?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a `HashMap<Long, ClientProperties>` that I'm putting on the ServletContext at startup.

```
//During application-startup:
//getProperties() returns HashMap<Long, ClientProperties>
context.setAttribute("clientProps", clientManager.getProperties());
```

ClientProperties is a POJO with 5 attributes that i need to access in my jsp.
Basicly I need to get the correct POJO (by HashMap-key) and access its properties in my jsp.

More spesific (for example purposes), one of the POJO attributes is `clientLogo`
In my jsp i now have:
`<img src="<c:url value='/images/logo.png'/>" alt="Logo">`

I need to replace the path to the logo-file with the clientLogo-property of the POJO.
The HashMap-key to use should be extracted from the User-object stored in the session. It can be retrieved like this: `${sessionScope['user'].clientId}`

Any ideas?
Using struts2 and spring btw if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get an attribute `foo` from the servlet context, you use the same syntax as to get it from the session, but replace sessionScope by applicationScope.

But you have so many nested things here that you should define variables:

```
<c:set var="map" value="${applicationScope['clientProps']}"/>
<c:set var="mapKey" value="${sessionScope['user'].clientId}"/>
<c:set var="pojo" value="${map[mapKey]}"/>
<c:set var="clientLogo" value="${pojo.clientLogo}"/>

<c:url value="${clientLogo}"/>
```

Note that this is typically the kind of hard work that you should not have to do in the view. Implement the retrieval of the image path in the controller, in Java, and make it available as a property of your action/form, and access it directly from your view.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Very helpful! The reason im doing it in the view is because this is the header.jsp, decorated by sitemesh. Can the header.jsp access struts-action-properties?

Comment: I don't see why it could not. But I don't have much experience with Struts2 and don't know how your app is configured.